# Highcharts export chart along with outer div

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

Can we do this:

1. I am using the highchart export for exporting the highchart, but when i click on the export button, I get only the chart with white background. Instead Can I get along with the div , where the chart is residing, also alone with the background color what ever the div has. Please look at the image for clear understanding

[image]

When I click on "Download PNG image", I get only the chart section, like:

[image]

but is it possible to download the image along with the div I mean the chart should include "SPEND BY SCREEN" div the blue line below it and then the chart.

Comment: Make "Spend By Screen" the title of your chart?

Answer (score 0):

Exporting server can translate only SVG to image/pdf - it won't take any HTML tags to be converted. Instead set [`chart.backgroundColor`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.backgroundColor).